# How To Convert Numeric Value Into Words?

Tags: google-bigquery

is there any string function that can convert numeric values to words?

Sample Data:

A. Numeric Value: $1000

TO

B. String Value: One Thousand Dollar

Reference (But this was done on Google Sheet)

- https://www.listendata.com/2013/12/convert-numeric-value-into-words-using.html

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION number2text(number INT64)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
  const first = ['','one ','two ','three ','four ', 'five ','six ','seven ','eight ','nine ','ten ','eleven ','twelve ','thirteen ','fourteen ','fifteen ','sixteen ','seventeen ','eighteen ','nineteen '];
  const tens = ['', '', 'twenty','thirty','forty','fifty', 'sixty','seventy','eighty','ninety'];
  const scales = ['', 'thousand', 'million', 'billion', 'trillion'];
  let word = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < scales.length; i++) {
    let tempNumber = number%(100*Math.pow(1000,i));
    if (Math.floor(tempNumber/Math.pow(1000,i)) !== 0) {
      if (Math.floor(tempNumber/Math.pow(1000,i)) < 20) {
        word = first[Math.floor(tempNumber/Math.pow(1000,i))] + scales[i] + ' ' + word;
      } else {
        word = tens[Math.floor(tempNumber/(10*Math.pow(1000,i)))] + '-' + first[Math.floor(tempNumber/Math.pow(1000,i))%10] + scales[i] + ' ' + word;
      }
    }

    tempNumber = number%(Math.pow(1000,i+1));
    if (Math.floor(tempNumber/(100*Math.pow(1000,i))) !== 0) word = first[Math.floor(tempNumber/(100*Math.pow(1000,i)))] + 'hundred ' + word;
  }
  return word;
""";
SELECT numeric_value, number2text(numeric_value) string_value
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Below is example output

[image]